# Is it true that if two open sets in a topological space intersect each other and share the same boundary, they are the same?

Tags: general-topology

Suppose we have a topological space $(X,\mathcal T)$. Open sets $A,B$ have the following properties:

$A\cap B\ne\emptyset$

$\partial A=\partial B$

Then $A=B$. Is it correct? If so, how to prove it?

Comment: How about $A$ is the interior of the unit disk, and $B$ is the complement of the unit circle?

Comment: @JoshKeneda: they do not intersect.

Comment: @Christopher: then the boundary of the ring is different from the boundary of the ball.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Sorry, I meant that $B$ should include both the interior and the exterior of the unit circle.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As pointed by Josh Keneda, $A=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2<1\}$ and $B=\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\partial A$ give a counter-example.

You may have a more convoluted conter-example by considering the basins of attraction, in $\mathbb{C}$, for the Newton's map applied to $p(x)=x^3-1$. Assuming that for some $w\in\mathbb{C}$ the iterates $\varphi^{(n)}(w)=\varphi(\varphi^{(n-1)}(w))$ converge, with: 
$$\varphi(x) = \frac{1}{3x^2}+\frac{2x}{3},$$
they converge to some third root of unity, but $A_1,A_{\omega},A_{\omega^2}$ (with the obvious meaning) share the same boundary:

$\hspace2in$[image]

so $A_1\cup A_\omega$ and $A_1\cup A_{\omega^2}$ give another counter-example.

Answer (score 21):

Other answers have shown this need not be true in general.  However, it is true if you assume $A$ and $B$ are both connected.  Indeed, $\partial A\subseteq \partial B$ implies $A\cap B$ is closed as a subset of $B$, and hence must be all of $B$ since it is also open in $B$ and nonempty.  Similarly, $A\cap B$ must be all of $A$ as well.

Comment: Another way of saying this appeals to the language of frames, which are complete Heyting algebras. Taking set-theoretic complements on the equality $\partial A = \partial B$ yields $A \cup (A \Rightarrow 0) = B \cup (B \Rightarrow 0)$ in the Heyting algebra of open sets, so $B$ is contained in a union of disjoint open sets $A$, $A \Rightarrow 0$, and therefore contained in $A$ by connectedness of $B$ and $A \cap B \neq \emptyset$. Similarly, $A$ is contained in $B$.

Answer (score 15):

Take the discrete topology on say the natural numbers, and let $A$ and $B$ be distinct sets with non-empty intersection. Their boundaries are empty, so they have the same boundary.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A=B \cup C$ where $C$ is open and closed, $B$ is open, $B$ and $C$ are disjoint and neither $B$ nor $C$ are empty. Then $A$ and $B$ have the same boundary.

Comment: This works as long as you additionally assume $B$ and $C$ are disjoint; I've edited in that assumption.

Comment: right i forgot to type it in